# Minecraft PS4 Not Loading Saves?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I have the newest version of Minecraft on the PS4 (Rabbits, Armor Stands, ect.) and I deleted all but the newest saves for each world and the most recent overall save. The most recent save is marked "Save Cache" and is from  2/1/2016, and the other three are all the most recent for each world; 2/1/2016, 1/29/2016 and 1/18/2016.  They all appear when looking at system data, but if I open minecraft, I'm greeted with an empty continue block with no worlds.

Is there any way to make my worlds show up? Or a way to un-delete the old data?

Comment: How have you deleted the data? using minecraft or something external?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to retain your deleted worlds OR retain the previous save data if your world has been reset unless you have backup save data.

Comment: While I'd prefer awarding the bounty to an answer that recreates the index file etc to fix the issue or at least list what can be tried again, this is the correct answer without delving into PS4's painful inner workings.